# What does the word "stage" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "**swirling vortex at the stage’s end**" in the following text (not available online):

*As you move peacefully along, stars of different colours will distract you away from the main path. Follow them and you’ll be led to special artifacts. 
Just Collect these and take them to the **swirling vortex at the stage’s end**.*

I am not sure if the word "stage" is used figuratively or literally here.

The text is from the description of the game "Little White Rocket". Here is a description of the game from a different source:

Little White Rocket is an inexpensive tappable toy, where each touch launches your craft along a path of stars, some of which aren't visible until you get close or complete a particular orbit.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you think *stage* means? https://youtu.be/K90spcuj_wY?t=98 shows a swirling vortex...

Comment: https://www.yourdictionary.com/stage-of-the-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used in the sense of definition 5a from [the Merriam-Webster Dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stage):

> 5 a : a period or step in a process, activity, or development

In particular, it is common to talk about a game having multiple "stages", which are distinct parts of the game (or story, etc) you must proceed through in order.